# How do I make a Django model instance to relate to another model instance

Tags: python, django

I want to have the **amount** under Rent to increment on the **amount** under Accounts. When a user types in the amount in Rent it should deduct or add in the amount in Account and should reset if paid or stay the same when not paid.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="Account number", unique=True, blank=True, null=False)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ALLOWED_CURRENCIES)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=MONEY_MAX_DIGITS, decimal_places=MONEY_DECIMAL_PLACES, help_text="Latest"                                                                                                  "balance", default=0, blank=False, null=True)

class Rent(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Account holder.")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=MONEY_MAX_DIGITS, decimal_places=MONEY_DECIMAL_PLACES)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these three strategies:

1. Compute the Account's amount dynamically. Instead of using the `amount` field, you can use a method (or maybe a cached property) like this:

   ```
   from django.db.models import Sum

   class Account(models.Model):

       # ...

       def amount(self):
           result = self.rent_set.all().aggregate(
               total_amount=Sum('amount'))
           return result['total_amount']
   ```

   This approach has the advantage that it is always accurate: no matter how you create and manipulate Account and Rent records, this method will always return the correct amount.

   It has the disadvantage of issuing a query every time you call it. This will have a performance impact.
2. Update the Account amount field when Rent is saved or deleted:

   ```
   from django.db.models import Sum

   class Account(models.Model):

       # ...

       def update_amount(self):
           result = self.rent_set.all().aggregate(
               total_amount=Sum('amount'))
           self.amount = result['total_amount']

   class Rent(models.Model):

       # ...

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().save(*args, **kwargs)
           self.account.update_amount()
           self.account.save()

       def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
           account = self.account
           super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
           account.update_amount()
           account.save()
   ```

   This approach has the advantage that the amount is stored into Account records, and therefore does not need to be recalculated every time you need it, only when a Rent object is saved.

   The disadvantage is that you *must* call `save()` and `delete()` on Rent objects. You cannot use, for example, queryset methods like `Rent.objects.all().delete(...)` or `Rent.objects.all().update(...)` because your custom `save()` and `delete()` won't be called.

   Another issue is that the amount won't be updated if you edit/delete Rent records at the database level, without going through your custom code.
3. Update the Account amount upon receiving [`post_save`/`post_delete` signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/) (thanks [user3375448](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3375448/user3375448) for the suggestion):

   ```
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
   from django.dispatch import receiver

   @receiver(post_save, sender=Rent)
   @receiver(post_delete, sender=Rent)
   def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
       instance.account.update_amount()
   ```

   This is essentially like the previous solution and it has essentially the same advantages and disadvantages.

   One improvement from the previous solution is that `post_delete` is sent when a queryset is deleted as well.

Comment: I would suggest using signals (post_save) instead of overriding Rent save method. I think it is cleaner specially that the update will be in different model.

Comment: @user3375448: thanks, excellent suggestion! I incorporated it in my answer

Comment: In the second suggestion do I make new instances for `account` and `Sum`?

Comment: @tonde: you have to add the `update_amount` method your existing `Account` class. The `Sum` class is already provided by Django, just import it: `from django.db.models import Sum`. Does it answer your question?